# My character starts spinning when i hinge a weapon onto him

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So im working on this fighting game but for some reason when i use a fixed hinge joint to connect my weapon to my character he starts spinning like crazy and the weapon is flying around the screen crazy fast as if not connected to him. Im still pretty new so bear with him, im sure its just some silly mistake, i did try to up the characters mass just in case the weapons weight were making him fall over, but it didn't do anything.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated! :)

To explain my situation further:

My weapon is several components made with maya and connected with fixed hinge joints. Besides the hinge joints the only thing on the weapon is a rigidbody which is why i expect it might have something to do with it.

The character has a player movement script, rigidybody and various colliders.

The movement script is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof(CharacterController))] 

public class MovementPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CollisionFlags collision;                                                        
    public float moveSpeed = 10;                                                            
    public Vector3 moveDirection;                                                           
    public CharacterController character;                                  
    public float jumpSpeed = 4;
    public float gravity = 4;

    void Start()
        {
            character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        }  

    void Update ()
        {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
             {
                 transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
             }
        if (character.isGrounded)
            {
                moveDirection = Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection).normalized;
                moveDirection *= moveSpeed;

                if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                {
                    moveDirection = Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Jump");
                    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection).normalized;
                    moveDirection *= jumpSpeed;
                }
            }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        collision = character.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like kinematics is involved with the rigidbody on the character's weapon, so try setting IsKinematic on the rigidbody to true.  It's unclear if there's a rigidbody on the character as well, but if there is then it should probably be removed because of the attached character controller.